# How to change css of the element from another page using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Please, help me!
I have two html pages. There is a `button` on the first page and a `div` on the second page. So, when I click the `button`, I want it to open the second page in the same window and change the background of the `div`.

Here is my code :

```
$(".button").on("click",function(){

    window.location.href="secondPage.html";
    $("div").css({background: "red"})

});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see how there's anyway to do this other than appending something to the URL and having code on the second page react to it. Or something in a cookie or session.  The second page has no idea how you got there otherwise.

Comment: The JavaScript on your fist page will no longer be able to execute when the second page has loaded. To do this you will need a way of persisting your intent from one page to the next with something like a cookie or parameter in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

**First page**

```
$(".button").on("click",function(){

    localStorage.setItem('button', 'clicked');
    window.location.href = "secondPage.html";

});
```

**Second page**

```
if(localStorage.getItem('button') === 'clicked'){
    $("div").css({backgroundColor: "red"});
}
```

To remove the Item in the localStorage-Object (if the background should not be changed conditionally) use:

```
localStorage.removeItem('button');
```

Small **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/13w7krzt/1/)**

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

**Note:** the localStorage-Object is only available in IE Version > 7. The other major-browser will work.

Comment: AFAIK With local storage, web applications can store data locally within the user's browser. So after click if user directly access the secandpage.html what will happen??? It still find the item and make the div red isn't it??

Comment: @Ashwath If the div should not be red after the button is clicked once, you can remove the localStorage in an page unload-event or similar

Comment: Right... I think you edited your answer now. :-) initially removeitem was missing so asked... Thank you.. :-)

Comment: @im1dermike yes you're right, I forget to mention that, but it's described in the reference, too. I edited my post to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use query string... When you click the button along with URL pass a query string  window.location.href="secondPage.htm?src=btnClickl";

And in second page.HTML look for SRC query string. If pressent , change the div color...

Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

The code should be placed on second page, and from that call the object "Parent" to ask whether it is null or not, in this case, if it is null, you can validate using the HREF property of the PARENT object to see if it is correct page and then change the color of the DIV.

Code in second HTML like to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if (windows.document.parent != null)
{
$("div").css({background: "red"});
}
});
```